# Add an admin level to a database

Tags: php, mysql

I have created a database but want to add a admin to the database how can this be done.

I already have Username,firstname,lastname and password which works but just need the extra line which is for the admin

Thanks

Comment: add new column in phpmyadmin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is not very clear, but if you are talking about a database table consist of users, you can,

1. just add a boolean column to make someone admin
2. add a text column like userType for multiple types of accounts
3. add a separate table as permissions and add columns for each and
   every permission access.

Then you can later check with the database to see if user has access/permissions

Comment: @user6107183 Welcome!

Answer (score 0):

1) If you want to create an Admin User Account for MySQL, connect to the MySQL server with a MySQL client program and execute the following command:

```
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'admin'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Change the word “admin” to whatever username you want to use for the admin account and change “password” to whatever password you want to use for that account.

2) IF you are talking about handling the Roles for users, add a column e.g."Role"

Check this as well [MySQL Admin User Account](http://blog.infusiontechsolutions.com/mysql-how-to-create-an-admin-user-account/)

Happy if this helps !